# Setup DocuSign E-signature using Angular and .net core api

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I'm setting up DocuSign using .net core api and angular.

I am new to DocuSign and i need to integrate it within my application to get a document signed.

What is the simplest way?

Comment: Please guide me.

Comment: There's usually documentation for things like this. Did you try anything?